# 'r' is invalid after a value. Expected either ',', '}', or ']'

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to Deserialize string to class with this structure:

```
  // this is my json
    {
      "MethodName":"PRC_SET_COMMISSION_STATIC",
      "Input":"{"reqType":"U","sapId":17000100,"offerType":5,"commissionRate":4,"accountNo":null,"fromDate":"2022-05-29T00:00:00","toDate":"2029-05-29T00:00:00","userId":"13601360"}"}
```

And this is my class which I want to get this values:

```
public class ProcessRequestRequestModelCl :AuthenticationModelCl
    {
        public string MethodName { get; set; }
        public string Input { get; set; }
    }
```

So what I do to achieve this is something like this:

```
ProcessRequestRequestModelCl RequestModel = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProcessRequestRequestModelCl>(ParameterStr);
```

but I get this error: **'r' is invalid after a value. Expected either ',', '}', or ']'**
problem is something with `"Input":"{"reqType":"U","sapId":17000100,"offerType":5,"commissionRate":4,"accountNo":null,"fromDate":"2022-05-29T00:00:00","toDate":"2029-05-29T00:00:00","userId":"13601360"}"` . I was wondering how should I Pass json as string to input value.

Comment: That input is actually invalid JSON, which is why you're getting this error. Specifically you surrounded the object 'Input' with quotes, treating it as a string, then you left unescaped quote marks inside that string making the entire thing basically nonsensical to the analyzer. Remove the quotes around the object (`"{...}"` to `{...}`), or escape the quote marks if you expect it to be a string.

Comment: @AlphaDelta so how can I handle this behavior? I want my input fill like this.

Comment: Generally if it cannot be interpreted programatically, it cannot be fixed programatically. I'd say this requires someone to manually fix it to be compliant with the JSON standard. TheTanic's answer is the solution in this particular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need to have the inner json as a string, you need to escape the quotes like this:

```
{
    "MethodName":"PRC_SET_COMMISSION_STATIC",
    "Input": "{\"reqType\":\"U\",\"sapId\":17000100,\"offerType\":5,\"commissionRate\":4,\"accountNo\":null,\"fromDate\":\"2022-05-29T00:00:00\",\"toDate\":\"2029-05-29T00:00:00\",\"userId\":\"13601360\"}"
}
```